# Should I look up my credit report or score before applying for a credit card?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, credit-score, credit-report

Right now I have two Credit Cards, Amex and a Visa through Wells Fargo.

I am planning changing over to Chase Freedom card for their 5% cash back. Part of the sign ups, depending your your credit, can get you $200 cash back just for signing up.

My question is, should I checkout my credit report *before* getting a card? Or simply sign up and see what they give me?

Answer (score 3):

If you're planning to apply anyway - then just apply, you'll get whatever as a pleasant surprise.

If you want to apply **in order to** get the bonus - then obviously it would make sense to check that you're eligible for it prior to applying.

Note that if the criteria is "credit score", then you'd better make sure which score exactly they're going to use, and pay to get that particular score. There are several different formulas that provide different numbers on different scales, and service providers that provide the "check your score service" and creditors may be using either of them (or combinations).

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to check your credit report even if you don't plan to apply for any cards. Every agency allows you to get one free report a year.

However if you apply for a credit card and get rejected you are entitled for another free report (which i believe will contains the credit score as well).